# I am making a bot in telegram connected with google sheet using App script. And I have a problem that the data is not saved to the table that I select

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, telegram-bot

I seem to have checked everything, but the data is not recorded in the table.
I created the sheetName variable and described it as if everywhere, but the bot still does not write data to the table.
I will be very glad to help! Below I will take a screenshot of how it looks in the Telegram bot

```
function doPost(e) {
  let contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  if (contents.callback_query) {
    // Button click processing
    let chatId = contents.callback_query.message.chat.id;
    let data = contents.callback_query.data;

    if (data === "Messages" || data === "Messages2" || data === "Messages3") {
      // The user has selected a category, we store it in a variable
      let sheetName = data;
      let messageText = "Enter the data for the table: " + sheetName;

      // We send a message to enter data
      sendText(chatId, messageText);

      // We save the selected category in the user properties
      setUserSheet(chatId, sheetName);

      // Відповідаємо на callback_query
      let callbackQueryId = contents.callback_query.id;
      let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/answerCallbackQuery?callback_query_id=" + callbackQueryId);
      Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    }
  } else if (contents.message) {
    let chatId = contents.message.chat.id;
    let messageText = contents.message.text;

    // Перевірка команди "/start"
    if (messageText === "/start") {
      sendSheetButtons(chatId);
    } else {
      // We save data in a table or send buttons
      let sheetName = getUserSheet(chatId);
      if (sheetName) {
        let item = text.split(";");
        // We get a table object
        let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

        // We record the data in the table
        sheet.appendRow([ new Date(), item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4], item[5], item[6]]);

        // We send a confirmation about saving data
        sendText(chatId, "The data is stored in a table: " + sheetName);
        
        // We send buttons for choosing a category
        sendSheetButtons(chatId);
      } else {
        // We send an error message
        sendText(chatId, "Error: No table selected. Select a category.");
      }
    }
  }
}

// Function to save the table selected by the user
function setUserSheet(chatId, sheetName) {
  userStates[chatId] = sheetName;
}

// Function to get the table selected by the user
function getUserSheet(chatId) {
  return userStates[chatId];
}

// A function to send buttons to select a table
function sendSheetButtons(chat_id) {
  let INLINE = {
    "inline_keyboard": [
      [{"text": "Messages", 'callback_data': "Messages"}],
      [{"text": "Messages2", 'callback_data': "Messages2"}],
      [{"text": "Messages3", 'callback_data': "Messages3"}]
    ]
  };

  let data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      text: "Select a category:",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(INLINE),
    },
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage", data);
}

// Function for sending a text message
function sendText(chat_id, text) {
  let data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
    },
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage", data);
}
```

I want to make a bot so that when a button is selected, I could record information in different sheets in a Google sheet

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to be a clear, concise question rather than a long summary of your project. Also take the [tour].